# C# Using a struct

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, monodevelop

I am using Mono Develop For Android and would like some help with using an array of structs.

Here is my code:

```
public struct overlayItem
{
    string stringTestString;
    float floatLongitude;
    float floatLatitude;
}
```

And when using this struct:

```
overlayItem[1] items;
items[0].stringTestString = "test";
items[0].floatLongitude = 174.813213f;
items[0].floatLatitude = -41.228162f;

items[1].stringTestString = "test1";
items[1].floatLongitude = 170.813213f;
items[1].floatLatitude = -45.228162f;
```

I am getting the following error at the line:

```
overlayItem[1] items;
```

> Unexpected symbol 'items'

Can I please have some help to correctly create an array of the above struct and then populate it with data.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the section on C# structs on the MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saxz13w4.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your struct like:

```
overlayItem[] items = new overlayItem[2];
```

Also you need to define your fields in the struct as public, to be able to access them outside the struct

```
public struct overlayItem
{
    public string stringTestString;
    public float floatLongitude;
    public float floatLatitude;
}
```

*(you may use [Pascal case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for your structure name)*

Comment: +1 for adding Pascal Case and pointing to the properties to be public.

Comment: @Asif: Fields, not properties.  While there are times when structures should have properties which behave semantically different from fields, if a structure member is going to behave like a public field, it should be a public field.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to declare the struct array for two elements is

```
overlayItem[] items = new overlayItem[2];
```

If you do not know the exact no of items you can also use list.

```
List<overlayItem> items = new List<overlayItem>();

items.Add( new overlayItem {
               stringTestString = "test";
               floatLongitude = 174.813213f;
               floatLatitude = -41.228162f; 
           }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your struct array like so:

```
overlayItem[] items = new overlayItem[2];
```

Remember to declare it with [2] as it will have 2 elements, not 1!  Indexing an array might start at zero, but defining an array size does not.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample code shows you need two items, so you need to declare the array of structs with length 2. This can be done with:

```
overlayItem[] items = new overlayItem[2];
```